# Function arguments have changed: how to refactor the code, changing as little as possible

Tags: c++, refactoring

There is a C++ function that calculates something (I am not sure if C++ matters here at all, anyway...). It is called in 50 or more places. Now it turned out that this function works wrongly. And in order to work correctly it needs three more arguments.

How can this code be refactored most efficiently in terms of the number of necessary changes and compactness.

BTW newly added arguments are such that it is not reasonable to have default values for them. They should be always passed to the function.

Many people asked for an example. Here it is:

```
//old syntax of function
int f(int a1, int a2)
{
    return a + b;
}

//new syntax of function
int f(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
{
    if (a3 == 10)
    {
        return a1 + a2;
    }
    else
    {
        return a1 + a2 + a4 + a5;
    }
}
```

**Does this example help? I need a way of doing this using a general approach, like a design patterns, like a principle of refactoring, but not for a specific example...**

Comment: If there are acceptable defaults for the additional three arguments you could add three trailing default arguments. This would mean the existing invocations would recompile with modification.

Comment: Can you give an example, how you want to see the new function being used.

Comment: 50 doesn't seem so many. What's wrong with just letting your compiler find all the calls and doing each one by hand. Would force you to have a good look at the code which is a very good thing. I would be cautious of some sort of automatic way of doing this.

Comment: @john I'd +1 that if it was an answer, since it is a better suggestion then using default values, or greping the function's name in an IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on where the three arguments come from. If we can't have default values and it is not possible to create a common pattern for the extra parameters, then you may have no alternative but to attack each of the 50 calls in groups. In this case, you'd keep the original call and make a direct copy with a slightly different name. You then move gradually over so that eventually all the calls call the new function with the extra parameters. You can then retire the old one.

On the other hand, if we can start with defaults or at least make them independent of the calling code then the following might be a good plan. The thing to bear in mind is that as a large change, this would presumably have to be done in phases to control the potential impact if anything went wrong.

First, I would change the name of the function from `xxxx` to `xxxx_<tag>` where `<tag>` is a handle for the change - possibly a bug # from a defect tracker or change management system. Then I'd create a new function called `xxxx` which simply calls `xxxx_<tag>` recompile everything. So far so good:

```
void xxxx_tag(int p1, int p2)
{
    // ....
}

void xxxx(int p1, int p2)
{
    xxxx_tag(p1, p2);
}
```

Next I'd change the signature of `xxxx_<tag>` to add the extra three parameters and the call to it. Now I'd rebuild again:

```
void xxxx_tag(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5)
{
    // ....
}

void xxxx(int p1, int p2)
{
    // XXX, YYY, and ZZZ and constants or at least can be derived at this point.
    xxxx_tag(p1, p2, XXX, YYY, ZZZ);
}
```

Key point here is also to add comments for future maintainers describing why this wrapper exists. Unfortunately, this is as far as some of these changes get so code gets left behind the purpose of which isn't immediately obvious.

I would then plan to phase in the 50 changes in say groups of five or ten so that you change your original call to the new call:

```
xxxx(p1, p2);
```

becomes:

```
xxxx_tag(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
```

Each section of calling code can be individually tested so that your are happy that (a) it works like it always did (i.e. fully backwards compatible) and (b) it fixes any problems.

Finally, once all this is done, you can then do a single change to remove the new function `xxxx()` and rename `xxxx_<tag>` to `xxxx` Again, you'd have to fully rebuild and test.

**Conclusion**

Whichever way you go I'd recommend:

1. Do it in stages - this minimises the risk of something going wrong.
2. Test, test and test again - again, this reduces your exposure to problems.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer! But this is not a solution this is an advice how to do what I don't want to do, instead I want to have a smart solution. Anyway thanks for your help. Your advises are valuable for sure!

Comment: Narek: You can take a look at Fowler et al. for advice on refactoring. I've done a fair amount of this and the above is the way I've done it. I'd be interested in what you come up with but would be very cautious of a 'smart' solution as they tend to mask problems. I stick by the two points in my conclusion - nothing beats breaking the problem down and testing thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

You can define default values for those 3 params and you will need to change only places where they have to be. Or use `find` in your IDE in whole project and correct them.

Comment: For my case default values can not work. And I am asking about a trick of how passing that new arguments without passing. For example, I can define them as global variables, but this is not a good approach, definitely. So it there a better way?

Comment: I think 50 times is not so bad. If you cant pass them by default, how can you define them as global? That means that they have same value. Where is logic?

Comment: Logic is that I change last three arguments in global namespace and call two argument function then. This function can retrieve the new values from the global variables from those global variables.

Comment: Then you need to change your design. Use some config manager or some similar thing

Comment: @Narek, it's better you give a code example in your post, rather than explaining in freestanding comments.